# My computer loses internet connection while router is ok

Tags: windows-7, internet, connection

It happens when I play games mostly. My desktop pc loses its internet connection (connected via ethernet) for a small amount of time (1-2 sec), dropping from games and raidcall and every other programm that uses internet.My laptop in the same time keeps having internet connection via wireless(always leave a stream on from twitch.tv to check). I've changed all cables but nothing happened.I have re-installed my network driver (have Asrock H77M for mobo) , switched to Linksys WAG200G from Thomson 585 v8 , still not fixed , disabled windows defender still not fixed, checked with MBAM for malware , still not fixed and disabled IPv6 cause I've read sometimes it bugs with IPv4, still not fixed and I disabled some other programms that used internet connection but still nothing happened.I have disabled windows updates (have win7 64bit on a new pc), and I use eset smart security 5 as an antivirus.My ISP says it's not my internet dropping and I can see it on my router - all LEDs working properly but I lose connection on my desktop.Also I've unchecked the energy option at the device management -> network adapter.
EDIT : I've read somewhere about NVIDIA and ASUS having something to do with that problem but they didn't elaborate much.I am using NVIDIA and ASROCK(which was ASUS ago iirc) just in case this helps.

Comment: Have you verified this problem isn't just simply your ISP? You should enable Windows defender that wouldn't cause you to lose your internet connection.  Your ISP has every reason to claim its not them, have them come out, verify ALL their equipment.  I had a problem like this and it ended up being my ISP.

Comment: Yes I've contacted my ISP many times and it's not on their side.I'm telling you that one of my computers only lose connection and not the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was ESET Smart Security 5 blocking UDP port 5355 which resulted in games + other programms losing connection with their respective servers. I tried to add that port to firewall's trusted zone but it wouldn't work. Just uninstalled it and changed to avast.

Answer (score 1):

You've mentioned that it happens when you play games mostly. It sounds like your computer is overheating.

Comment: Can't be.It's brand new and temps are around 30-40 celsius.

Comment: @user2192519 - Just because your comptuer is new doesn't mean it can't overheat.

Comment: True but I told you it is around 40 degrees and isn't overheating. plus I can't understand how overheating would make it lose internet connection instead of turning off or something else.

Comment: What is around 40 degrees? Your CPU? How about the GPU? If your wifi adapter located closely to the GPU it may be overheating. Try to use the ethernet cable instead

Comment: Nothing gets over 50 degrees with temps running around 40 when gaming.And I say  again I am using ethernet and not wireless...